# Pager Adapter Error while try to display server images in slider

Tags: android

I'm getting an error when trying to load the server images into the slider using view pager.

Here is my code:

```
private ArrayList<ImageModel> GetImages(final String business_id){

    final ArrayList<ImageModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

    final Serverurl serverUrl = new Serverurl();
    serverUrl.url("Registration","showOtherImages");
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST, serverUrl.domain_url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("images");
                        if (jsonArray.length() == 0) {
                            //Toast.makeText(MySlider.this, "Hello im blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            for(int i = 0 ;i < 4; i++)
                            {
                                ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
                                imageModel.setImage_dynamic(serverUrl.other_image + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_path"));
                                list.add(imageModel);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Toast.makeText(Imageslider.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("business_id",business_id);
            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Imageslider.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    return list;
}
private void init() {

    mPager =  findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mPager.setAdapter(new ImageSliderAdapterDynamix(Imageslider.this,imageModelArrayList));

    CirclePageIndicator indicator =
            findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(mPager);

    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

//Set circle indicator radius
    indicator.setRadius(5 * density);

    NUM_PAGES =imageModelArrayList.size();

    // Auto start of viewpager
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }

            mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        }
    };
    Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, 3000, 3000);

    // Pager listener over indicator
    indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            currentPage = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

        }
    });

}
```

**Here is log error screen shot:**

> 06-20 02:50:09.232 18880-18880/com.example.aamer.aurangabad E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.aamer.aurangabad, PID: 18880
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 0, found: 4 Pager id: com.example.aamer.aurangabad:id/pager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class adapters.ImageSliderAdapterDynamix
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1135)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:662)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:624)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:616)
>           at com.example.aamer.aurangabad.Imageslider$4.run(Imageslider.java:139)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: @user902300 what I'm doing wrong any help???

Comment: Did you read the exception? "The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged!" seems pretty clear to me. If you change the content, you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, otherwise your app will crash. Please do your own debugging to identify which lines are causing the crash, then post those. None of us want to read through pages of code, no matter how amazing it is.

Comment: @Campbell showing error at line number 139 in logcat but i dont understand why its giving that error

Comment: @Campbell in this line "mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);"

Comment: @Campbell when I add drawable images to slider it works perfectly fine but when I try add dynamic image then it give the above error.Any help is appreciate thank you